# SF remove unwanted json input with ParamConverter

Tags: json, symfony, fosrestbundle

Is that possible to use ParamConverter with json input and remove unwanted fields ?

In my entity Folder, i have the fields name (string) and createdAt (Datetime). I don't want the use who send a new Folder choose the value of createdAt.

json input:

```
{
  "name": "F name",
  "createdAt": "01/02/03"
}
```

Should save the entity only with the name.

How can i ignore the field createAt (or any unwanted input) ?

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post("/folder")
 * @Rest\View(StatusCode = 201)
 * @ParamConverter(
 *     "folder",
 *     converter="fos_rest.request_body",
 *     options={
 *        "validator"={ "groups"="Create" }
 *     }
 * )
 *
 */
public function createAction(Folder $folder, ConstraintViolationList $violations)
{
    if (count($violations)) {
        return $this->view($violations, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($folder);
    $em->flush();

    return $folder;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it !

I use the JmsSerializer groups.

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post("/folder")
 * @Rest\View(StatusCode = 201)
 * @ParamConverter(
 *     "folder",
 *     converter="fos_rest.request_body",
 *     options={
 *        "validator"={ "groups"="create" },
 *        "deserializationContext"={"groups"={"folder_create"}}
 *     }
 * )
 *
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request to pick and choose which items from a JSON object you want to use.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function createAction(Folder $folder, ConstraintViolationList $violations, Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->request->get('name');
    #do whatever you want with $name now ...

    if (count($violations)) {
        return $this->view($violations, Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($folder);
    $em->flush();

    return $folder;
}
```

Comment: I can use $folder->getName(). That's not the point ;) I want to automatically remove items in the json before the creation of Folder.